# Shifting elements in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to run a code that shifts the values of a list three spots to the right. For instance, I have a list [1,2,3,-3,15,6,71,42] and I want to make the output [-3,15,6,71,42, 1,2,3 ], but the current output of the program is [-3, 15, 6, 71, 42, 8, 8, 8].

I cannot find the error, but the professor wants me to change **ONLY ONE LINE OF CODE** to fix the error. So the error must not be too hard to find. Except I can not seem to find it :D

```py
def foo1(values): 
   return values[0] 

def foo2(values):
   for i in range(1,len(values)):
      values[i-1] = values[i]

def foo3(values,c):
      values[len(values)-c] = len(values)

def main(): 
   values = [1,2,3,-3,15,6,71,42] 
   k = 3
   for r in range(k): 
      a = foo1(values)
      foo2(values)
      foo3(values,a)

   print("Here is the shifted list to the left for " + str(k) + " time:" )
   print(values)
```

Comment: No no no! I just feel like I'm making no progress trying to figure it out, and I'd like some help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
  values[len(values) - c] = len(values)
```

To this:

```
  values[len(values) - 1] = c
```

Right now you're using the item's **value** (c) as an index instead of "appending" it to the shifted list in each iteration.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I knew it had to do with this line. I saw the length of values equaled 8 and knew that I had to change this line. Thank you for clarifying it!

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is overly complicated - there's no need to have three different functions. Assuming you have a list called `data`, you can simply do:

```
for i in range(number_of_shifts):
    data.append(data.pop(0))
```

Comment: I think writting code in a more 'open' way is better when learning programming

Answer (score 0):

Other solution:

```
data = data[k:] + data[:k]
```